# Allocating m rooms of varying capacity to n booking requests of varying sizes

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, optimal-strategy

I am developing a system which performs automated room allotment. We have finite number of rooms, each with varying capacity. Each booking request is also of varying size. The goal here is to minimize number of rooms used and minimize room capacity wasted. The only reason why we want to minimize number of rooms used is to prevent booking requests being split into too many rooms. For example, Allocating (d,e) is better than allocating (a,b,c,d). The primary goal is to minimize wasted capacity.

I hope the following example will help you to understand the above narrative.
Let say we have 6 rooms with the following capacities:

| a | b | c | d | e | f |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 14 |

> avg. room capacity = 5

Let say we have two booking requests with following group sizes (# of people): 7, 10

| r1 | r2 |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 10 |

***Assuming*** processing booking requests in the descending order of their size may lead to optimal solution, we start with r2 (size 10).

**Option 1:**

We can see that we could use rooms (a,b,c,d) or (d,e) or just (f). With (a,b,c,d) option we use 4 rooms with 0 wasted capacity. With (d,e) option we use 2 rooms with 0 wasted capacity. Hence (d,e) is better than (a,b,c,d). If we go with (d,e), the only option for r2 is room f, in which case we would have used 3 rooms with wasted room capacity of 7.

**Option 2:**

Now if we go with just room f, we use 1 room with 4 (14-10) wasted capacity. However, r2 can be fulfilled with either (c,d) or (a,e) with 0 wasted capacity. Total 3 rooms used and wasted room capacity is 4.

Option 2 is better.

**Tie breaker** (not claiming it is correct or logical)
Let say we arrive at multiple solutions. For example, if we have to decide between 2 room 7 wasted capacity and 3 rooms 4 wasted capacity, then we can take avg room capacity (in this case 5) as 1 room equivalent. 3 rooms 4 wasted capacity can be considered equivalent to 2 rooms 9 (4 + 5) wasted capacity. So 2 room 7 wasted capacity is better. We can also tweak this room equivalent parameter (c). Default it to avg. room capacity. If we want to go ahead with minimum wasted capacity only, we can set c to 0. With c = 0, 3 rooms 4 wasted capacity option would be better.

This narrative and examples show the problem at hand and also the attempts I have made to solve them.

**Objective Function**
The "goodness" of the allocation may be measured by the following expression: (r*c)+u, where r is total number of rooms used, c is a constant (c>=0) and u = unutilized or wasted capacity. **The less the better.** The optimum allocation can be determined by the least value of the goodness factor. The constant c may be 0 if we only want to optimize for capacity regardless of number of rooms used.

**Update**
I initially wrote that "Assume bookings cannot share rooms." But we need to solve this for shared rooms scenarios as well. We can use unoccupied capacity for allocation. For example, room f (14 capacity) will have unused capacity of 4 after allocating r2. This should be considered while allocating r1. Updated table will look like this:

| a | b | c | d | e | f (updated) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 4 |

I need your help to answer the following:

1. Is there any well known algorithm to solve this problem. Knapsack and Bin packing come close but don't fit the problem completely.
2. If not, how to efficiently allocate rooms? Please provide algorithm with time complexity analysis.

Comment: It's not room allotment, it's room allocation. An allotment is one small area in a shared garden area. If have an allotment where I grow potatoes and salad.

Comment: Examples are usually bad at explaining. State the rules. Your "tie breaker" rules seem bizarre. Actually, they are not "tie breaker" rules. "Tie breaker" rules should be a set of secondary rules which decides which solution to take when more than one are optimal due to your primary rules.

Comment: "minimize number of rooms used and minimize room capacity wasted" - You can't simultaneously minimize two different quantities.  Often, the solution that minimizes the first does not minimize the second.  Consequently, this problem statement does not seem well-defined.  The normal way is to provide an objective function that maps any candidate allocation to a number that measures how "good" the allocation is, and then ask to maximize this objective function.  Can you define such an objective function?

Comment: We need a well-defined problem statement.  An example is not a substitute for a general specification of the problem.

Comment: If you have two rooms each of size two and one room of size six. If the group have size 4, then optimizing the number of rooms puts the group in the room of size six, meanwhile optimizing the the wasted capacity divides the group into the rooms of size 2.

Comment: gnasher729, @D.W., as you have pointed out, my English is poor, I lack ability to provide well defined problem statement. But the problem is real. I tried to come up with an object function. You'll find it at the end of the problem statement. Awaiting your response.

Comment: It looks to me like you are asking two different versions here.  Rather than putting them in the same question, I would suggest that you ask them separately.  Also changing the question in a significant way after you receive an answer has some issues; I encourage you to think carefully about exactly what your question is before posting, so that you don't waste our time and we don't waste your time answering questions that aren't the question you want answered.

Answer (score 3):

One plausible approach is to use integer linear programming.  Introduce 0-or-1 variables $x_{q,r}$, where $x_{q,r}=1$ means that room $r$ is assigned to request $q$.  Then you can write down linear inequalities that characterize the properties of a valid solution: e.g., $\sum_r \text{capacity}(r) x_{q,r} \ge \text{size}(q)$ for all $q$, $\sum_q x_{q,r} \le 1$ for all $r$, etc.  Then you are trying to minimize
$$\sum_{q,r} x_{q,r} + \sum_q (\sum_r \text{capacity}(r) x_{q,r} - \text{size}(q)).$$
This can be solved with an off-the-shelf ILP solver.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just updated the question. We need two solutions, one where room sharing is not allowed and another where it is allowed. Please read the "Update" narrative for more details.

Comment: "This problem is at least as hard as the subset sum problem" - can you explain how? Is the subset-sum problem to reducible to OP's problem?

Comment: @VHS, I thought it was when I wrote my answer, but as I reviewed it now, I cannot construct a valid reduction, so I've removed that statement.  Sorry for my sloppiness.

Comment: @VHS I can see more easily that it (the decision variant of it) is reducible to knapsack problem. In fact, it's just a generalization of knapsack problem. It still likely allows pseudopolynomial solutions though.